# RMI programme: Client side giving Error

Tags: java, netbeans-7

I am creating RMI program for my class assignment in Netbeans. It is a simple RMI program and The server side is working properly. But as I run my client side file. It ends up giving me error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java.net.SocketPermission" "127.0.0.1:1099" "connect,resolve")
```

plus it is saying some error at line 26 at client code.
For clear understanding I am giving full code of all three files.

**Interface.java :**

```
package RMI;

import java.rmi.Remote;
import java.rmi.RemoteException;

public interface DemoInterface extends Remote {

    public String SayDemo() throws RemoteException;

}
```

**Server.java**

```
package RMI;

import java.rmi.RemoteException;
import java.rmi.registry.LocateRegistry;
import java.rmi.registry.Registry;
import java.rmi.server.UnicastRemoteObject;

public class Server implements Interface{
    public Server()
    {
        super();
    }
    private  String message;
    public Server(String msg) throws RemoteException
    {
        message = msg;
}


public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        DemoInterface h = new Server("Hello");
        DemoInterface stub = (DemoInterface) UnicastRemoteObject.exportObject(h,0);
        LocateRegistry.createRegistry(4096);
        Registry registry = LocateRegistry.getRegistry("127.0.0.1",4096);

        registry.rebind("Hello", stub);

        System.out.println("Server is connected and ready to use");
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println("server not connected\n"+e);
    }
}
    @Override
public String SayDemo() throws RemoteException {
    System.out.println("Server.saydemo override");
    return message;
}
}
```

**Client.java**

```
package RMI;

import java.rmi.NotBoundException;
import java.rmi.RemoteException;
import java.rmi.registry.LocateRegistry;
import java.rmi.registry.Registry;

public class Client {
public static void main(String[] args) {
  if(System.getSecurityManager() == null)
    {
        System.setSecurityManager(new SecurityManager());
    }
    try {

        Registry reg = LocateRegistry.getRegistry("127.0.0.1", 4096);
        System.out.println("in try after reg locate");
        DemoInterface h = (DemoInterface) reg.lookup("Hello");//Error Showed on this line by netbeans
       System.out.println(h.SayDemo());
    }
    catch(RemoteException | NotBoundException e)
    {
        System.out.println(""+e );
    }
}
}
```

please guide me where I am wrong. Thank You in advance.

Comment: This probably isn't the issue since you said the server is running, but port 1099 is reserved in basically every OS. Try 4096 or greater. Also, please, please, please come up with a better name for your interface than `Interface`.

Comment: Edited As per your suggestions on both port no:4096 and Interface=DemoInterface still getting the same error @musical_coder

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You set a `SecurityManager` in your client `main` method. Did you also provide a security policy file? The default policy is not very permissive, and denies, among other things, Socket operations.

You can specify a policy that allows all permissions to all code bases like so.

```
grant {
    permission java.security.AllPermission;
};
```

add it to your command line for invoking `java`. Substitute `mypolicy` for your policy file and `SomeApp` for your main class. *Note the two `=` characters in the second argument*

```
java -Djava.security.manager -Djava.security.policy==mypolicy SomeApp
```

Note that this is not a safe policy to run for RMI in a production environment (RMI can load remote code bases).

Proper use of the `SecurityManager` class and policy configuration is a complex topic, for further reading I suggest [Java SE 7 Security Documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/) and in particular [Default Policy Implementation and Policy File Syntax](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/PolicyFiles.html)

Comment: thank you for the knowledge about the security privileges by "SecurityManager". After getting your point I commented those lines and now my program is running successfully......Thank you Dev and @musical_coder

Comment: @NAPSTER: glad you got it working. Since Dev's answer seemed to be what solved your problem, please click the checkmark to accept it.

Comment: @NAPSTER just remember, this setting gives the RMI service unrestricted access to the client, just so you know ;)